# Unusual HTTP response on ASP.NET Core web app hosted in Azure in Chrome

Tags: azure, google-chrome, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.0

I host a React & ASP.NET Core web app in an Azure App Service. I'm encountering an isolated and bizarre (to me anyway!) issue relating to the post-login process in my application.

We use Okta for authentication and the login process looks like this:

1. User navigates to our website
2. On page load when not logged in, authorize attribute redirects to the `'/api/auth/login'` controller action
3. `'/api/auth/login'` invokes challenge and redirects to Okta
4. User logs in to Okta and is redirected back to callback URL specified in OpenID connect middleware
5. Web app redirects back to `'/api/auth/login'` to check if user is authenticated then redirects to `'/'` to render home page

In **chrome, in azure and over https only** step 5 above does not redirect to `'/'` and instead the call to `'/api/auth/login'` is returning a 200. Nowhere in my controller action do I return a 200 here. This works locally when using chrome and HTTPs so it seems to be isolated to my Azure environment.

Chrome request/response dumps of HTTP vs HTTPS in Azure are below. The HTTP response is what I'm expecting, I've got no idea where the HTTPS response is coming from.

---

**HTTP with expected response from `'/api/auth/login'` call:**
[image]

---

**HTTPS with unexpected response:**
[image]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scaffolding framework we used for our react application was registering a service worker which was returning this 200.